# Modify the Windows shell menu

Tags: windows, shell

I'm sure everyone has been annoyed by a cluttered, slow and ugly shell menu after you install some apps, so I was wondering if there is a way to remove some entries from appearing in the shell menu. For example:

[image: Menu]

This is my shell menu, and I don't want entries like WinRAR for security essentials to appear there. Is there any way to get rid of them? I know some apps have built in settings to disable this but some don't.

Answer (score 4):

ShellMenuView, freeware from Nirsoft, does exactly what you want.

Ref:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html

Answer (score 3):

*VLC and WinRAR* appear here because you indicated it during installation. It can be easily disabled through **application options** or by reinstalling the application with more appropriate options.

For *WinRAR*, go to *Options* → *Settings* → *Integration* → *Context menu items*. Also note that *WinRAR* let you choose what items may appear, thus removing the less used "Compress and email" etc. stuff.

If I remember well, this is the same thing for *Windows Media Player*.

Probably *Microsoft Security Essentials* and *Malwarebytes' Anti-Maware* do have options too.

*Tortoise SVN* works from Explorer. So if you remove it from the context menu, **you will not be able to use it any-longer**. If you don't need it, uninstall it.

---

**Modifying registry settings by yourself is not a good idea in this case**. Sometimes, applications may recreate the registry keys (I think it is the case with WinRAR, but I'm not sure), or you can encounter unexpected behavior.

Most of the applications ask you if you want to create items in context menus. In this case, very often they enable you to change it through options. Some applications do not ask you anything and do not let you to disable anything: they are **malware**, and are good candidates for being definitively removed.

Answer (score 2):

This stuff is stored in the registry; see http://windowsxp.mvps.org/slowrightclick.htm for some details.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible that you can remove them:

- Via setup or add/remove programs as it could be an install time option.
- OR
- Via Tools | Options...

When I cleanedup mine, most of them were options in the programs themselves.  I only went to the registry as last resort.  If you do that, make sure to export your tree before...

Answer (score 1):

Try MenuMaid, quick and easy

http://www.sdsoftware.org/default.asp?id=11403

more info about the program here
http://lifehacker.com/5501911/menu-maid-cleans-up-your-right+click-context-menu